# Get Meta Value for all Posts via $wpdb

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

I wrote a function which should give you the value of a meta key for all of the posts. I am not sure why my query is not working. It gives me an empty `array` as output when I `var_dump` the query. The value of the meta key is stored in `array`, so I am using `unserialize` to convert the mysql array to PHP array.

**The Function**

```
function wp_postquiz_total_completed_quizes_by_user( ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $mylink = $wpdb->get_results("
                        SELECT $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value * 
                        FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
                        WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_pq_users_answered_quiz_on_post'",
                        ARRAY_A);


    $array = unserialize($mylink);

    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value *
```

It looks like you're trying to select `meta_value` and "everything" even though `meta_value` is included in `*`. Do one or the other:

```
SELECT $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value
```

or

```
SELECT *
```

If the `meta_value` is the only field you're interested in then the first one is the way to go. For future reference, you can get any SQL errors by calling:

```
$wpdb->print_error();
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @mtinsley . One last question, I also wan't to get the post id with the meta value. I am trying to add `LEFT JOIN`, but its seems not to be working. I modified this `SELECT $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value, $wpdb->postmeta.post_id` and added `LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta.post_id`

Comment: The post ID is already in the postmeta row. Do you mean you want to get the post (not just ID)? If so you may want to use `WP_Query` with a meta query. Create another question if you get stuck.

Comment: Just created a new question, I'll be very thank full if you can get this solve for me. Thanks. [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744511/gets-post-id-and-meta-value-in-an-array-via-wpdb)